# Why puma webserver fails in development with multiple requests at a time?

Tags: ruby, rack, puma

I have following puma-config:

```rb
workers 0 # single mode

threads_count = 2
threads threads_count, threads_count

rackup DefaultRackup
port 3200
environment ENV["RACK_ENV"]

on_worker_boot do
  App.stop(:orm)
end
```

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.3.2 (ruby 2.7.0-p0) ("Sweetnighter")
*  Min threads: 2
*  Max threads: 2
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 286
```

The backend is a simple ruby GraphQL-API. I have a react frontend.
If the frontend requests multiple requests at a time, not all requests are processed properly. There happens weird failures like this at the frontend, because the response only partially arrives.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 91 of the JSON data
```

It seems like the server aborts a request when a new one comes in.

If I set the thread_count to 1

```rb
threads_count = 1
```

there's no error, the requests are processed sequentially.

What's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: The error suggests this is an GraphQL error rather than puma issue - I saw this error a lot working with graphql on ruby and it can be anything in the api backend - syntax error, string evaluation, uncaught nil etc.
I would guess that the problem with multiple requests is not puma related but rather that the responses for some of the requests are corrupted.  Maybe some requests trigger a different branch of an if statement, go into a different method than the rest or something along the way?
Seeing the requests/responses might help in helping you.

Comment: Thanks @kkp. But a failing response looks like this `{"data":{"bookings":[{"center":{"id":"545445","name":"Greek","numbe`. It is really cut off.. Furthermore there are 3 requests. Which of the 3 fails is random. If I start my server with `bundle exec rackup` (cluster-mode, 1 worker, min threads 0, max threads 5), I see following error: `2022-01-19 11:44:26 +0000 Read: #<Rack::Lint::LintError: Content-Length header was 90, but should be 9447>` The requests are simple master data requests, no parameters, everytime the same response. Do you have another idea?

Comment: You might be experiencing a race condition between the threads... i.e., overwriting the same String object or using class / global objects / variables. This is very likely the situation if you aren't experiencing any errors when using a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read my question carefully, you will find several clues pointing to a concurrency problem.

> threads_count = 2

> If the frontend requests multiple requests at a time, not all requests are processed properly

> If I set the thread_count to 1, there's no error

At the time, I didn't see those clues and didn't know what was going on ;). Often you can't see the forest for the trees.

@Myst could see the clues and pointed me in the right direction.

I'm using great hanami-api for my API and the controllers are hanami-controllers (1.3). Here's a code-snippet, which includes the concurrency-bug:

```rb
class MyAPI < Hanami::API
  scope "api" do
    scope "graphql" do
      post "endpoint", to: App["controllers.graphql.endpoint"]
    end
  end
end
```

Then I found this useful text in the docs:

> An Action is mutable. When used without Hanami::Router, be sure to instantiate an action for each request. The same advice applies when using Hanami::Router but NOT routing to mycontroller#myaction but instead routing direct to a class.

Meanwhile there is already hanami-controller 2.x, and they are thread-safe by design.

But in my case I had to fix my code to:

```rb
class MyAPI < Hanami::API
  scope "api" do
    scope "graphql" do
      post "endpoint",  to: ->(env) { App["controllers.graphql.endpoint"].call(env) }
    end
  end
end
```